# A part of A is eaten from the question title

Tags: bug, design, title

Despite of responsiveness the left bottom part of "A" letter when it comes as a first letter in the question title is eaten (obscured):

> [image: Ate a]

> [image: Zoomed]

Tested for FF and Chrome on Windows 7

Comment: No repro on Firefox Nightly 65.0a1, Arch Linux (using the Arial font).

Comment: Also, [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ2Lj.png) should make it clearer what you mean. And [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Io0B.png) shows what it looks like for me. Feel free to include these in your post.

Comment: @Xufox thanks for the image. Added to the question.

Comment: Wow. Just... wow. Congratulations.

Comment: @Won't sorry, but I didn’t circled another s for that much congratulations